# Consuming OnPrem SignalR service from Azure App service/Function app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am new to signalR. We have an existing on prem signalr service that we want to consume from Azure either app service or function app and finally that will be consumed by client applications hosted in another cloud provider. I have mostly seen examples on how to consume signal r service directly from client, so i am not sure if the app service can be a client to a signalr service.
secondly how do i go about setting the api to be a consumer and a service at the same time. Is this possible? Would i need to set up another Hub on the api side? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need information regarding:

1. Consume on-prem signal R service from Azure Functions/Az App Service
2. Azure Functions/Az App Service can be consumed by client apps hosted in another cloud provider

One of the workaround is to do for the above is:

> Consume On-Prem signal R service from Azure Functions / Azure App Service

**SignalR Service** is a fully managed Azure Service that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications over HTTP. This real-time functionality allows the service to push messages and content updates to connected clients using technologies such as WebSocket. As a result, clients are updated without the need to poll the server or submit new HTTP requests for updates.

So, You can consume this SignalR Service using **Azure Functions**.
**All you need to do is send messages to the Azure Functions, which will send it to SignalR who will broadcast to listeners.**

There is a [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config) provided as step-by-step to achieve the above.

> Azure Functions/Az App Service can be consumed by client apps hosted in another cloud provider

I'm not sure about the client app from another cloud provider but the workaround of **consuming the azure function by the client application** is like:

If the client application is ASP .NET Core Web App, add the **Azure Function URL** with Code in `appsettings.json` file:

```
  "AppSettings": {
  "AzureFunctionURL": "https://[AppName].azurewebsites.net/api/[FunctionName]?code=<API_Key>"
  }
```

And the step-by-step instructions with an example is provided in an [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-and-consume-azure-function-from-asp-net-core/).

For more information, please refer these documentations:

1. Would i need to set up another Hub on the api side? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core
2. [Real-time serverless applications with the SignalR Service bindings in Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/real-time-serverless-applications-with-the-signalr-service-bindings-in-azure-functions/)
3. [Enable automatic updates in a web application using Azure Functions and SignalR Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/automatic-update-of-a-webapp-using-azure-functions-and-signalr/?WT.mc_id=WebWednesday-c9-niner)

Comment: Hi, I understand that i can enable push notification for appservice and use it as rest service and signalr , Not sure why Azure Signal R Service should be used? Can i do with out it?

Comment: Yes, you can do! Here is a list of all [Realtime backend API](https://stackshare.io/realtime-backend-api) frameworks so take a look and choose what suits your needs the best.

Comment: I am using appservice and selfhosting signalr service instead of deploying Azure SignalR service. Everything works locally but when deployed to azure "Error: Failed to start the transport 'LongPolling': Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code '404'" . I am using LongPolling because webapp service has a front door. Should this work in Azure?

Comment: Hello @Gauls, Please create a new thread request for the above issue with clear error details and the steps that you tried to resolve as well as how you followed the steps of self-hosting and deploying to Azure, So that it will reach more community members to address it!